# How to install wfastcgi on server without internet?

Tags: python, wfastcgi

I have to install python package wfastcgi.py to get my web app run on individual server. IIS and Flask are working properly I guess. I tried a lot of ways and I have no idea. I want to start all over again with concrete instructions. Pip also doesn't work, I am using python through Anaconda3.
What I need to do to make wfastcgi work? By "working" I mean command "wfastcgi-enable" gives positive answer in cmd. Every tip is priceless.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you mean that install it locally,you can download the `.whl` and use `pip install xx.whl` to install it without Internet.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work :(

Comment: It didn't work?Why?

Comment: A situation envolved to where few minutes I saw good message after using wgast-enable-script and app didn't worked, but right now all I can see is home page of site, when I use search button, it shows error "The website cannot display this page". On terminal it says to change paths, but I'm sure all paths are good right now. Any ideas, what is wrong? Where should I  look for ?

Comment: You can add a tag `Django`.Maybe it can help you.